# Jquery show not working only on elements with a certain class

Tags: jquery, show

I have this strange problem where jquery .show() doesn't work only on some elements.

I have this checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="classcheck" value="1" id="id1">
<input type="checkbox" class="classcheck" value="2" id="id2">
```

That are used to display different items based on what i choose.

Here is the code that does that:

```
$(document).on('change','.classcheck',function()
{
    $('.classcheck').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {

            switch($(this).val())
            {
                case '1':
                    $('.class1').show();
                break;

                case '2':
                    $('.class2').show();
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch($(this).val())
            {
                case '1':
                    $('.class1').hide();
                break;

                case '2':
                    $('.class2').hide();
                break;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

And an example element:

```
    <div class="item form-group class1">
          <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">This is an 
element: </label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="el1" name="el1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" style="width:40%" >
      </div>
    </div>
```

All the elements as soon as the page loads are set to hidden.

Basically only some elements with class1 are showed but the majority stay hidden and that seems to happen only to elements with that class.

Also some elements might have two classes like:

```
class="class1 class2"
```

Comment: You haven't added an event handler for the checkboxes, so actually nothing should happen based on you actively un-/checking them.

Comment: Change your each function to change function, it will work as expected.

Comment: @connexo sorry i missed it, i modified the question

Comment: value of the checkbox is 0 or 1.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin value of the checkbox is whatever has been assigned to it.

Comment: Why not use toggle instead of hide and show ?

Comment: If some have both classes `class="class1 class2"`. Your current solution (and the answers) assume only a single class.   You'll need to define how that will work.  eg if you click 1 but not 2, will class1+class2 be shown?  if you click 1and2 then uncheck 1, will 2 still be shown as it has class2?   This seems the most logic UX, but your code will not handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution :
>
> - You need to use checkbox change event
> - use `$(this).prop('checked')` to find checkbox is checked or not

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.classcheck').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                switch ($(this).val()) {
                    case '1':
                        $('.class1').show();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $('.class2').show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else {
                switch ($(this).val()) {
                    case '1':
                        $('.class1').hide();
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        $('.class2').hide();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });//end change event

    });//end each loop

});//jq
```

```css
.class1,.class2{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="classcheck" value="1" id="id1"> Checkebox 1

<input type="checkbox" class="classcheck" value="2" id="id2">  Checkebox 2

<div class="item form-group class1">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        This is an element 1 :
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="el1" name="el1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" style="width:40%">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="item form-group class2">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        This is an element 2 : 
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="el1" name="el1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" style="width:40%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your event to something like below, you don't need each function inside document change event.

```
 $(document).on('change', '.classcheck', function (ev) {
        var clickedBox = ev.currentTarget;
        if ($(clickedBox).is(':checked')) {
            switch ($(clickedBox).val()) {
                case '1':
                    $('.class1').show();
                    break;

                case '2':
                    $('.class2').show();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            switch ($(clickedBox).val()) {
                case '1':
                    $('.class1').hide();
                    break;

                case '2':
                    $('.class2').hide();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help you

```
 <script>
    $('.classcheck').on('click', function() {
        $('.classcheck').each(function() {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {

                switch($(this).val())
                {
                    case '1':
                        $('.class1').show();
                    break;

                    case '2':
                        $('.class2').show();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch($(this).val())
                {
                    case '1':
                        $('.class1').hide();
                    break;

                    case '2':
                        $('.class2').hide();
                    break;
                }
            }

        });   
    })

</script>
```